# Game sharing with different Id and passwords

Tags: itunes

we already have an id and password with around 5 devices on it, we have just gotten another device but with a different Id and password. My question is can I/how do I get the games that are on the other devices onto the new device.

Answer (score 1):

you can consider
[Family Sharing](http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/)